# Custom title for UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to set custom title of UILocalNotification. How can I achieve this.Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

When creating a notification, you can set the text of the notification, and the text of the second button. The title will always be the same as the name of your app as it appears on the homescreen. The title cannot be changed because lets the user know which app sent the notification. The only reason I can think of why you would want to change it is if your app is pretending to be another app, which you probably shouldn't be doing anyway.

And, even if you do find a way, Apple will not approve your app, as there is no officially documented or permitted method to do this. So there's no point trying, because your app will get rejected anyway.

Comment: This is unfortunate - I am developing an app for a medical company and they want to use some desecration due to the sensitive nature of the reminder. On the other hand I can completely understand the "security" reason as well...

Comment: I understand, but this restriction is imposed so the user can easily tell which app sent the notification, because the notification is labelled with the app's name and has the app's icon next to it.

Comment: Apple does it for itself, but doesn't allow us! Check out by adding a reminder. They don't show 'Reminder' app's name but only Reminder's title!!

Comment: No, @PartiallyFinite, that is not the only reason a developer would want to change the title.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set Custom "Title" For Local Notifications. It will be always the name of your app.

Comment: Native apps do that, Phone, Calendar, and so on. They set whatever title they want.
But I've yet not seen any non-native app doing that. It seems possible on Mac OS notification center, but unfortunately not in iOS yet.

Comment: But now you can change it by using alertTitle property.

Comment: Yes, iOS 8.2 and later has at.

Comment: nope. that property is only used for in Apple Watch.

Comment: This is what i see from iOS documentation `@property(nullable, nonatomic,copy) NSString *alertTitle NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_2);`

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 8.2, you can now set a custom title for local notifications, using the `alertTitle` property of a `UILocalNotification` object.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertTitle

Comment: If you read carefully, alertTitle is actually only used to display the notification in the Apple Watch.

Answer (score 0):

**You can notif in this  way also**

```
localnotification =[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

[localnotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:[lodatepicker countDownDuration]]];

[localnotification setAlertAction:@"Launch"];

[localnotification setHasAction: YES];

[localnotification setAlertBody:[lotextview text]];

 [localnotification setSoundName:musicString];

localnotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

[localnotification setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localnotification];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for swift applications:

```
var localNotification: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
localNotification.alertTitle = "Notification Title Goes Here"
```

Comment: alertTitle is only used to display in the Apple Watch.

Answer (score 0):

```
localNotification.alertTitle = @"Welcome";
```

Use this property to provide a short description of the reason for the alert. You may specify a string with the text you want to display or you may specify a string to use as a lookup key in your app’s Localizable.strings file. The default value of this property is nil.

Title strings should be short, usually only a couple of words describing the reason for the notification. Apple Watch displays the title string as part of the short look notification interface, which has limited space.

Availability
Available in iOS 8.2 and later.

**Example:**

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
localNotification.alertTitle = @"Welcome";
localNotification.alertBody = @"Thank You for installing Application";
localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

**Responce:**

[image]

for more detail you can read the apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/alertTitle)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `alertBody property`.

```
UILocalNotification *_notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

_notif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.5];
_notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
_notif.alertBody = @"My custom notification text";
_notif.alertAction = @"Open!";
_notif.soundName = _AudioFile;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:_notif];

[_notif release];
```

hope this helps.

---

**EDIT**: Ops, i understood text, not title.
Title is the name of the App.